# Check/count if file array is empty in php

Tags: php, arrays

$_FILES array:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" name="smth[]" id="smth1" />
<input type="file" name="smth[]" id="smth1" />
<input type="file" name="smth[]" id="smth1" />
```

How can i check if file array is empty? (no files selected).

**PHP:**

```
if (CHECK) {

...operating with $_FILES...

}
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function any_uploaded($name) {
  foreach ($_FILES[$name]['error'] as $ferror) {
    if ($ferror != UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

if (any_uploaded('smth')) {
  // ..operating with $_FILES...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
if(isset($_FILES) && count($_FILES) > 0){
...
```

?

Comment: Yes, something like this, only that doesn't work - `$FILES` is always set.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you'd need to iterate through your $_FILES and check for UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE in the error-key. See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php for more.

Apart from that, there are countless ways of checking if an array is empty! i.e. empty() or count()

Answer (score 0):

just check for the file's name:

```
foreach($_FILES as $key => $val){
  if(strlen($_FILES[$key]['name']) > 0){
    //here we got a file from user
  }else{
    //no files received
  }
}
```